# Можно ли list View разбить на две колонки

Tags: android

Можно ли list View разбить на две колонки, если нет с помощью какого элемента можно сделать [похожий](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT1KJVLciWofCQ2bVnrUtszs6nDrAy8zPXT1bcWz-ZLemg_FZYdiw) вывод элементов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенном скриншоте представлен не ListView а recyclerView с кастомным адаптером. Суть в том, что вы создаете разметку для одного элемента данного списка, в вашем случае это квадрат с картинкой и двумя подписями. Для того чтобы создать такой квадрат, вам нужно воспользоваться элементом cardView в котором уже будут размещены остальные (imageView + textView+textView) елементы. Вот к примеру хороший [ресурс](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/web-service-backends-and-custom-fragments/custom-adapters-with-recyclerview) чтобы понять как сделать такой список. Дальше вы добавляете gridView с двумя колонками и там уже размещаете этот список, так же можно регулировать кол-во колонок. Если что-то будет непонятно, или возникнут сложности, с радостью поможем. Удачи :)

### UPDATE:

вот код из моего проекта, адаптер:

```
public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> alName;
    private ArrayList<Integer> alImage;
    private Context context;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    MainAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> alName, ArrayList<Integer> alImage) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.alName = alName;
        this.alImage = alImage;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.tvSpecies.setText(alName.get(position));
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(alImage.get(position));


        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int k = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                switch (k) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, блабла.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(context, "no service))", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alName.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView imgThumbnail;
        TextView tvSpecies;
        ItemClickListener clickListener;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgActivity);
            tvSpecies = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clickListener.onClick(view, getPosition(), false);
        }
    }
}
```

вот в главном классе подключение колоночного отображения списка:

```
alName = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("text1", "text2"));
alImage = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.pict1, R.drawable.pict2));
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mAdapter = new MainAdapter(MainScreen.this, alName, alImage);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

и вот приблизительная отрисовка элемента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.03dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgActivity"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#ff444444"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

код я писал вначале своих работ над этим проектом, сейчас структура приложения полностью изменена, так что небольшие (большие) ошибочки могут встречаться, но вроде должно быть все нормально.

P.S. [ссылка1](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/introducing-multiviewadapter-7f77e5758d3f) + [ссылка2](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/) 
+ я брал этот ресурс вначале [ссылка4](https://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial)

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста какие-нибудь интересные сайты по современному дизайну android приложений, желательно англоязычные.

Comment: сайтов много)) лично я гуглю, или смотрю на приложения и копирую дизайн)

Comment: А можете подсказать как правильно реализовать переключение между listView и cardView как в этом приложении первые два скрина https://xistore.by/instructions/prilozhenie_zametki_v_smartfonakh_xiaomi/

Comment: вам нужно будет создать два вида разметки, одна на основе cardview а вторая на основе listview, одна будет грузится по умолчанию, и они должны будут заменяться при на нажатии на кнопку, данные будут грузится как в одну так и в вторую разметку

Comment: тип два отдельных списка и по нажатии на кнопку менять их видимость?

Comment: либо так, либо можно поиграться с файлами разметки, переназначать разметку в зависимости от выбора кнопки, но вариант с видимостью на мой взгляд более хорош, например тем что приложение более вероятно будет нормально работать

Comment: Посмотрите сэмилы от гугл, там есть ответы на ваши вопросы по ресайклер вью итд. Есть базовые примеры дизайна. https://developer.android.com/samples/